# Tips/Tricks/Facts Reminder software?

Tags: windows

I am looking for a simple desktop application in which I can add, remove or edit some items (sentences, pictures, etc.) and it must show one of them (randomly) as a pop-up window on my screen based on a schedule. For example I want to see an item every 2 hours, or whenever I turn on my laptop, and I want them to be random. It actually reminds me something useful, tips, tricks, facts, etc. I didn't know what to google. That's why I'm here.

**I don't want a learning or To-Do application.**

Some example items:

- Drink more water.
- "*Two possibilities exist: Either we are alone in the Universe or we are not. Both are equally terrifying.*"
  **Arthur C. Clarke**
- *Ctrl+Shift+Esc* does the same thing.
- Your mom. [with a picture]

Comment: Could this be, say, an online webapp, which you would simply check every once in a while and see a new fact? Or do you want it to create a popup on your screen every two or three hours with a random "tip"?

Comment: I want an offline desktop application which creates a popup on my screen. Edited. :)

Comment: Do you want the content entirely under your control or do you want it to get a list of tips from somewhere (could be an external server, created at installation etc.)?

Comment: @NickWilde As I mentioned I want to add, remove or edit contents. So I want the content entirely under my control.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Anki](http://ankisrs.net).

Anki's algorithm shows you a fact just when you are about to forget it: Best timing for long-term memory.
The algorithm works so well that after 5 iterations you will probably have memorized the fact already.

You must enter facts as question/answer, for instance:

> Q: What is RTTI?
>   A: Run-Time Type Information (introspection in C++)

I am not sure about the desktop app (apart from [this addon](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/85158043)), but at least the Android app can show up when there are things to review.

You can add/edit/remove content.

*Disclaimer: I maintain AnkiDroid, the Android application for Anki.*

---

EDIT: Now that you have added examples, I see that some facts do not fit in the question/answer model. For such facts, put everything in the question field, and when the fact appears press `Space` then `2`. This will make the same fact re-appear at regular intervals.

Comment: Anki is a kind of learning application. I don't want to learn. I want to get reminded. I don't want a To-Do application neither. Edited. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The part of your original question that says `I didn't know what to google. That's why I'm here.` encouraged me to broaden the spectrum a bit... but I am sure you will get better answers than mine :-)

Comment: @Mowji , maybe you're getting mistaken between purpose and usage. Anki was designed as a learning application, but sure can be used in many more way than one and, to my opinion, would suit your needs pretty well.

Comment: @VicAche Maybe Anki works for somebody with this purpose. But it's not designed for this purpose. Even it can not show pop-up items (based on a schedule). Definitely I can get it to work in some ways, but it has a lot of differences with what I want.

Comment: I'm not saying it suits your needs, but I do think it is a legit answer, and your comment seemed a bit agressive to me.

Comment: It wasn't agressive. :) Why would it be?

Comment: BTW you mentioned "would suit your needs pretty well."